# Limiting access to a website based on IP address when .htaccess is not allowed

Tags: osx, webserver

I am trying to limit access to a website to a small set of IP addresses. I am a regular user on the Mac OSX web server. My first attempt at limited access was to create an `.htaccess`

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.0.1
```

where 192.168.0.1 is the IP address of the machine I want to allow in the sub directory of the website that I want to limit access to. As far as I can tell, the `.htaccess` file does nothing since I can access files in the sub-directory from both 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2. Presumably the administrators of the web server have not enabled [.htaccess override](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html).

In the top level directory of the website is a file called `.www_access`:

```
Options +Includes
```

I cannot find any information about this file. Copying the file to the sub-directory and adding the `.htaccess` stuff to give a `.www_access` of:

```
Options +Includes
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.0.1
```

sort of works. I can access the files in the sub-directory from 192.168.0.1 and cannot access them from 192.168.0.2, but when I try and access from 192.168.0.2 I get a "500 internal server error" and I was expecting a "403 access forbidden". Adding an error document redirect to `.www_access`

```
Options +Includes
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.google.com
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.0.1
```

has no effect.

Given I have no idea what `.www_access` is doing, I am not sure I should be going down this route. Is it possible to limit access to a website to a small set of IP addresses if the web server does not support `.htaccess` files?

The web server has PHP installed, but doesn't see to allow web pages to use it. If I create a php test file

```
#! /usr/bin/php
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and then ssh into the web server I can run it from the command line and get lots of information. If I then try and accesses it from a browser, I just get the code back. I think there are other scripting languages installed on the webserver, but as far as I can tell none are accessible from the web.

Comment: @Christopher added some information about scripting languages. The web server has PHP, but I cannot use it from the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to limit access to a website to a small set of IP addresses if the web server does not support .htaccess files?

The definition of the Apache virtual host can be changed without enabling `.htaccess` files. This is a bit faster anyway. Just ask them to limit the site to certain subnets.

```
<Directory "<file system path>">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.0.0/24
</Directory>
```

Comment: The web server is running on top of OSX/Darwin so it is pretty main stream. The [Apache tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) recommends not using `.htaccess`. I am not sure why the web server administrators disabled (didn't enable) php, but they are not going to change the set up.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got the web server admins to respond to me. For whatever reason they have decided to rename `.htaccess` to `.wwwaccess`. My issues with the error pages is do to an somewhat related issue with how the admins have setup the proxy/firewall.